# Trying to implement dark/light mode in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, colors, onclick

```js
document.getElementById("theme_change").onclick = function () {
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.borderColor = "#000";
        document.getElementById("theme_change").innerText = "Light Theme";
    } else if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f5deb3") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.borderColor = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementById("theme_change").innerText = "Dark Theme";

    }
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="color_change" class="btn">Change Color</a>
            <a href="#" id="theme_change" class="btn">Light Theme</a>
       </div>
```

I'm new in JavaScript and for some reasons I need to create a switch button to change the theme of my webpage.

I'm using the document.getElementById and the getElementByTagName
to do so.

But my problem is that when I click on the button once,only the background change and only the color of one of my buttons changes.When I click again on the button that is supposed to switch between the themes nothing happen.

On this page I have two buttons that change some colors on the page, the first one works really good so i can't figure out why the second one doesn't.

As explained before I can click on the theme_changer button one time, when I click on it the background changes (#000 -> #f5deb3), the color of the first button changes to (#f5deb3 -> #000) and the text of the second button change to (Light Theme -> Dark Theme) but not his color, it stays with the same color (#f5deb3) and when I click on it again nothing happens.

I tried changing the order of the lines in the JavaScript file to see if something was different and so to be able to see where the problem could be, but nothing changed.The same happened with the browser console, which  returned no errors.

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: `=` is for assignment. If you want to compare values, use `==` or `===`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, i've already tried this but with the '==' or '===' (in the if only of course) nothing happens at all

Comment: Nothing probably happens when you use `==` because the background color is neither `#000` nor `#f5deb3` when you first click.

Comment: I set the background to #000 in a css rule so when I load my webpage the background is #000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few drawbacks in your code.

1. `document.body.style.backgroundColor` gives a color string in the
   format of "rgb" not in "hex".
2. While using conditions within `if` statements, always use `==` or `===` instead of `=`.

Therefore, this code should work for you:

```js
document.getElementById("theme_change").onclick = function () {
if (document.body.style.backgroundColor === "" || document.body.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f5deb3";
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#000";
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.borderColor = "#000";
    document.getElementById("theme_change").innerText = "Light Theme";
} else if (document.body.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(245, 222, 179)") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#f5deb3";
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.borderColor = "#f5deb3";
    document.getElementById("theme_change").innerText = "Dark Theme";

}
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="color_change" class="btn">Change Color</a>
            <a href="#" id="theme_change" class="btn">Light Theme</a>
       </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw on another post that this backgroundColor method returns a RGB format color but I tried with the rgb directly and it didn't worked. I don't understand why the if(color === "") works to be honest. But thank you again.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! The reason behind the if(color === "") is, by default, the backgroundColor style of body is always empty unless we set some color to it. i.e, by either applying CSS or by changing the property like you did using Javascript.

Comment: I see, thank you really much for those explainations !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the original background color to the "Light Theme" background and change the `=` in your if statements to `==`. Also you are only setting the text color for the first element that has an `a` tag.  Cahange your code to something like this:

```
document.getElementById("theme_change").onclick = function () {
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "#000") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.borderColor = "#000";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].style.borderColor = "#000";
        document.getElementById("theme_change").innerText = "Light Theme";
    } else if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f5deb3") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor == "#000";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.borderColor = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].style.color = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].style.borderColor = "#f5deb3";
        document.getElementById("theme_change").innerText = "Dark Theme";

    }
}
```

Comment: I just changed my code to something like you wrote, thanks for the tip with the anchor tags, unfortunately nothing has changed, worse the button doesn't change the background at all...